# sum of a list row of a list, without using inbuilt sum()

Tags: python, sum, nested-lists

For a quiz question have to use nested list to find the sum of each row without using the inbuilt sum()

My code(1)

```
def row_sums(square):
    """ Takes a nested list and returns the sum of the row"""
    row_1 = square[0]
    for sum_1 in row_1:
        for sum_r_1 in sum_1:
            sum_row_1 = 0
            sum_r_1 += sum_row_1
            return sum_r_1
```

the problem with this is i get the int object is not iterable

or

My code(2)

```
def row_sums(square):
    """ Takes a nested list and returns the sum of the row"""
    row_1 = square[0]
    for sum_1 in row_1:
            sum_r_1 = 0   
            sum_r_1 += sum_1
            return sum_r_1
```

I only get the first item of the list in row 1. In this case that being the number 2

the input from the quiz server

```
square = [
    [2, 7, 6],
    [9, 5, 1],
    [4, 3, 8]
]
print(row_sums(square))
```

expected result
    [15, 15, 15]

I know what im trying to get atm is only the first row, but once i have that I can easily do the other rows

Comment: I'd probably write something stupid like `def totally_not_the_built_in_sum(items): return eval('+'.join(str(it) for it in items))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close:

```
def row_sums(square):
    sums = []
    for row in square:
        rowsum = 0
        for num in row:
            rowsum += num
        sums.append(rowsum)
    return sums
```

Comment: i didnt think of changing it to
    x = []

Now I feel dumb

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work is because

```
for sum_1 in row_1:
    sum_r_1 = 0   
    sum_r_1 += sum_1
    return sum_r_1
```

Every time you go to a new number you set `sum_r_1` back to `0`, then `return` it... so it goes through the first number, adds it, then immediately returns it without looking at any of the other numbers.

Instead, you want to set the beginning value and return **outside** the loop:

```
sum_r = 0   
for sum_1 in row:
    sum_r += sum_1
return sum_r
```

This will get you the first row. I would suggest making another attempt rather than taking a full solution from SO.

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple way it iterate through list of lists, adding inner list elements together and appending them to another list.

```
square =[
    [2,2,2],
    [1,1,1],
    [3,3,3]
]
sumLine=[]

for i in range(len(square)):
   s =0
   for n in square[i]:

        s = s + n


   sumLine.append(s)
   #results in [6, 3, 9]
```